# Laravel 7 custom login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm making a custom login in Laravel, and when I try to check login form's data I cannot log in. In register I hash the password to store it in db, so the login form's password field will never be equal to stored db.

Here's my create function, where I register the user:

```
   public function create()
{
    $this->validateFields();

    if (request('profileImage') !== null) {
        $this->storeImage();

        User::create([
            'username' => request('username'),
            'email' => request('email'),
            'password' => Hash::make('password'),
            'profileImage' => request()->profileImage->getClientOriginalName(),
        ]);

    }


    User::create([
        'username' => request('username'),
        'email' => request('email'),
        'password' => Hash::make(request('password')),
    ]);


    return Redirect::to(route('user.showLoginForm'));

}
```

validateFields and storeImage are not relevant for the question...

Here's my login function:

```
    public function login()
{
    request()->validate([
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    $credentials = array(
        "email" => request("email"),
        "password" => bcrypt(request("password"))
    );

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return 'exit!';
    }

    return 'Error';

}
```

Here's my login form:

```
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row pt-2">
        <div class="col-sm-12 justify-content-center">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4>
                        Login
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <form action="{{ route('user.login') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
                                    <label for="email">{{ __('E-mail') }}</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
                                    <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-form-label text-md-right">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-elegant">Iniciar sesión</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you don't hash the password in the credentials you pass to `attempt`: it takes the PLAIN version  .... also why are you writing you own login? all this stuff works perfectly fine and is customizable out of the box

Comment: If I use the plain password I cannot login. It the dame problem!

Comment: i guess we can assume that the `if` statement in your `create` method never gets hit?

Comment: The if statement in create method is to check the profileImage field. The problem I have is in login.

Answer (score 1):

Custom login 100% working without auth,

```
 use Hash;

$data->password = Hash::make(($request->password)); Encript Password

public function requestEmployee(Request $request)
{
if ($data = AddEmployee::where('name', $request->name)->first()) {
    $pass = Hash::check($request->password, $data->password);
    if ($pass) {
        echo "sucess";
    } else {
        echo "Password Not Valid";
    }
 } else {
    echo "Username Not Valid" . "<br>";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $password=Hash::check($request->password,$user->password);
```

use this it will return true or false

Or
just use

```
  $credentials = array(
    "email" => request("email"),
    "password" => request("password")
);
```

without bcrypt

Comment: Do you mean that I should use Hash::check instead Auth::attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Please try it:

```php
public function login()
{
    request()->validate([
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    $credentials = array(
        "email" => request("email"),
        "password" => request("password")
    );

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return 'exit!';
    }

    return 'Error';

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I think the plain password cannot be compare with hashed password stored in db, but I don't know how to fix it